# How do I loop through tweets to access geo information and add to an array

Tags: objective-c, loops, twitter, geolocation

How would I loop through the JSON returned by a TWRequest to get the geo information of a tweet? I am using the code below - I have marked up the bit I am unsure about. the text component works fine, I'm just not sure how to create the array of geo data and access this...

```
    - (void)fetchTweets
{
    AppDelegate *delegate = (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];


    //NSLog(@"phrase carried over is %@", delegate.a);

    // Do a simple search, using the Twitter API
    TWRequest *request = [[TWRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:
                                                         [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=%@", delegate.a]] 
                                             parameters:nil requestMethod:TWRequestMethodGET];

    // Notice this is a block, it is the handler to process the response
    [request performRequestWithHandler:^(NSData *responseData, NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse, NSError *error)
     {
         if ([urlResponse statusCode] == 200) 
         {
             // The response from Twitter is in JSON format
             // Move the response into a dictionary and print
             NSError *error;        
             NSDictionary *dict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:0 error:&error];
             //NSLog(@"Twitter response: %@", dict);

             NSArray *results = [dict objectForKey:@"results"];


             //Loop through the results


             for (NSDictionary *tweet in results) {
                 // Get the tweet
                 NSString *twittext = [tweet objectForKey:@"text"];
                 //added this one - need to check id NSString is ok??
                 NSString *twitlocation = [tweet objectForKey:@"geo"];

                 // Save the tweet to the twitterText array
                 [_twitterText addObject:twittext];

                 //this is the loop for the location
                [twitterLocation addObject:twitlocation];
             }

             dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

[self.tableView reloadData];

             });




         }

         else
             NSLog(@"Twitter error, HTTP response: %i", [urlResponse statusCode]);
     }];



}
```

Answer (score 1):

"geo" is deprecated and probably not filled at all. I far as I remember it was deprecated in Twitter API v1.0 too. Try this code:

```
- (void)fetchTweets
{
    AppDelegate *delegate = (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];

    //NSLog(@"phrase carried over is %@", delegate.a);

    // Do a simple search, using the Twitter API
    TWRequest *request = [[TWRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:
                                                         [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=%@", delegate.a]]
                                             parameters:nil requestMethod:TWRequestMethodGET];

    // Notice this is a block, it is the handler to process the response
    [request performRequestWithHandler:^(NSData *responseData, NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse, NSError *error)
     {
         if ([urlResponse statusCode] == 200)
         {
             // The response from Twitter is in JSON format
             // Move the response into a dictionary and print
             NSError *error;
             NSDictionary *dict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:0 error:&error];
             //NSLog(@"Twitter response: %@", dict);

             NSArray *results = [dict objectForKey:@"results"];


             //Loop through the results


             for (NSDictionary *tweet in results) {
                 // Get the tweet
                 NSString *twittext = [tweet objectForKey:@"text"];
                 //added this one - need to check id NSString is ok??
                 id jsonResult = [tweet valueForKeyPath:@"coordinates.coordinates"];
                 if ([NSNull null] != jsonResult) {
                     if (2 == [jsonResult count]) {
                         NSDecimalNumber* longitude = [jsonResult objectAtIndex:0];
                         NSDecimalNumber* latitude = [jsonResult objectAtIndex:1];
                         if (longitude && latitude) {
                             // here you have your coordinates do whatever you like
                             [twitterLocation addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@,%@", latitude, longitude]];
                         }
                         else {
                             NSLog(@"Warning: bad coordinates: %@", jsonResult);
                         }
                     }
                     else {
                         NSLog(@"Warning: bad coordinates: %@", jsonResult);
                     }
                 }

                 // Save the tweet to the twitterText array
                 [_twitterText addObject:twittext];

             }

             dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                 [self.tableView reloadData];
             });
         }
         else
             NSLog(@"Twitter error, HTTP response: %i", [urlResponse statusCode]);
     }];
}
```

Comment: Thanks demosten - would I place this in my 'for loop' where I currently have "NSString *twitlocation = [tweet objectForKey:@"geo"];" or outside? Thanks

Comment: the code is tuned to be in the place where `NSString *twitlocation = [tweet objectForKey:@"geo"];` line is. You could put it in a method passing your tweet variable as a parameter or place directly there replacing `return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@,%@", latitude, longitude];` with adding string to your array

Comment: I've added that in where you suggested but I'm getting "incompatable block pointer types on my line <code>     [request performRequestWithHandler:^(NSData *responseData, NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse, NSError *error) </code> in my TWRequest - any thoughts?

Comment: Hi demosten, I've added the full method to the original post - Thanks

Comment: Hello again - Sorry, a bit of an issue here. It is returning "Warning: bad coordinates: (null)" I have tried pasting my search into a browser and it is returning "geo":{"coordinates":[51.479323,-0.215097],"type":"Point"} so I'm not sure why the code is not returning this - Thanks

Comment: You should use this method https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/search/tweets. Though the old one might still work, it is deprecated and can stop at any time. Also you will need to add account information to `request` before calling `performRequestWithHandler`. Find some samples about it.

Comment: Hi, that is exactly what I have been using in my URL - [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=%@&geocode=51.479323,-0.215097,1mi", delegate.a]] I understand that I can get the co-ords without Authentication but the above returns a "NUL" for the co-ords. Doing this as a search string on a browser returns values - any thoughts? Thanks